# How to get uuid from block_content in twig template

Tags: hooks, theming

For custom block theming I need the uuid of the `block_content`. I created the variable uuid in `mytheme.theme`:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
   $variables['uuid'] = $variables['elements']['content']['#block_content']->uuid();
}
```

Now I get the uuid by calling `{{ uuid }}` in my `block.html.twig`. But I also get the error:

> Notice: Undefined index: #block_content in mytheme_preprocess_block()
>   AND the html is broken, it only includes the output of
>   block.html.twig.

Is something wrong with my function. Or is there another approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
function mytheme_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
    if ( isset($variables['elements']['content']['#block_content'])) {
       $block_content = $variables['elements']['content']['#block_content'];
       $variables['uuid'] = $variables['elements']['content']['#block_content']->uuid();
    }
}
```

Now it works!

When I want to get the uuid of my custom block referenced by entity reference:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
if ( isset($variables['elements']['content']['#block_content']))
{
    $block_content = $variables['elements']['content']['#block_content'];
    $variables['uuid'] = $variables['elements']['content']['#block_content']->uuid();
}
elseif ( isset($variables['elements']['content']['field']['0']['#block_content']))
{
    $block_content = $variables['elements']['content']['field']['0']['#block_content'];
    $variables['uuid'] = $variables['elements']['content']['field']['0']['#block_content']->uuid();
}
}
```